# xuggler rtcp streaming

Tags: java, video-streaming, xuggler, rtcp

can anyone tell me how can I create an rtcp stream with use of xuggler(without use RED5) . I use the MEDIATOOL api ant IMEdiaReader to decode the saved video container, but how can I stream in the rtcp? I see that I can't throw an IMediaWriter. I must use a new IContainer for the output?

thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `RTCP` or `RTMP`? To stream `RTMP` you should use appropriate URL like `rtmp://localhost/live/testStream`

Comment: Thank you. I use the code from here http://www.brokenmill.com/2010/08/xuggler-rtmp-howto/ to create the ouputcontainer and I get an error of                                                        "ERROR org.ffmpeg - RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 111 (Connection refused)
09:21:49.481 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.xuggler - URL: rtmp://localhost/live/tes; Error: could not open file (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:516)"

Comment: Code looks correct. Try to do the same with `ffmpeg` command line utility. You should have some server (like red5 or Adobe FMS) listening port 1935 (by default). Probably you have firewall blocking port access.

Comment: Can I stream without use an external server? rtmp or rtp?

Comment: You mean you want to serve RTMP yourself? Then you need to fork red5. I think better is to write your application as red5 app. If you want to stream peer-to-peer, then you need to use some peer-to-peer protocol like RTMFP. In this case you will need to encapsulate media into container yourself if Xuggler does not support it (I worked only with RTMP). Xuggler will help only with format conversion in this case.